# Solve a ODE with unknown nonhomogeneous term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE which was reduced from a PDE with boundary conditions $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ at $x$ on the boundaries. Is there a way to get a solution for the following

$$\frac{d H(t)}{dt} + \lambda H(t) = -2(A(t)+ B(t))$$

without knowing what $A$ and $B$ are?

Comment: Which method would you use? It's been a while since I've taken an math class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From chapter 2 of Antsaklis & Michel's [A Linear Systems Primer](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Linear_Systems_Primer.html?id=7W4Rbqw_8vYC):

---

[image]